# Issue with session redirect in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, redirect, heroku

I'm having a little trouble using sessions in rails 3. I will detail some of my work environment first.

I have an application hosted on heroku, let's say your URL is **http://myapp.herokuapp.com**

And I have a domain with **CNAME** pointed to heroku, let's say it's **http://www.myapp.com**

When I send an email from my app to the client, it contains a url to a restricted area of the application, then the way that is done is:

*http://www.myapp.com -> Email -> http://www.myapp.com/secret*

But how is a secret area the user is redirected to **http://www.myapp.com/log_in**

Here's the problem: The Rails saves the actual URL of the application, which in this case is *http://myapp.herokuapp.com*, and after login it redirects the user to *http://myapp.herokuapp.com/secret*! And I do not want it, want it to continue in the field *http://myapp.com.*

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Showing **any** relevant code would be useful.

Comment: Really? What kind of code you want to see ? Because rails do this think automatically. I send the guy to myapp.com/secret, but rails store the URL myapp.herokuapp.com/secret , and after login the user is redirected to that URL. I want to redirect him to the myapp.com/secret URL.

Comment: @Deefour He's basically asking how to set the default domain name on a heroku rails app. Seems like a good valid questions to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
redirect_to secret_path( host: 'myapp.com' )
```

or

```
redirect_to url_for( action: 'my_action', host: SOME_DEFAULT_HOST )
```

**edit**

I'm not sure i understood your question well - do you mean you *save* the URIs in the DB ?

IMHO, saving hardcoded urls can become a hassle.

If possible, try to save deconstructed URI parts instead of a full string path, so you can send the args to `url_for` or any path helper later (and tweak it as needed, or update your whole table at once to change the host for example).

If not, you can always parse the saved URI with any lib of your choice, and then tweak it before redirection

Comment: Thank you, thats it ! Btw, i don't save the URLS in DB, i keep them in environment variables, like ENV['HOST'], because my development env is localhost and production app is heroku. I'll just change this production env to myapp.com instead of myapp.herokuapp.com